# Fixed point of continuous function on compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove the map has a fixed point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118536/prove-the-map-has-a-fixed-point)

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a continuous function such that $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ for every $x,y\in X$ such that $x\neq y$.

a) Prove that $f$ has a unique fixed point by minimizing $d(f(x),x)$.
b)Prove that for any $x\in X$, the sequence $x,f(x),f(f(x)),\ldots, f^n(x),\ldots$ converges to the fixed point.