# convergence of continued nested function

Tags: convergence-divergence

Does $$\sin (x + \sin (x + \sin (x + \sin (x + ... ) ) )))  $$ converge to any limit? If so, to what?

Recursive plotting appears at times to come to same/similar profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the sequence

$$x_{n+1} = x_0 + \sin x_n$$

For any $x_0$, the function $x_0+\sin x$ is $1$-lipschitzian and maps the interval $[x_0 - 1, x_0 + 1]$ into itself. Therefore it has a unique fixed point in that interval, and the sequence $x_n$ converges to it according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118536/prove-the-map-has-a-fixed-point) modification of the Banach fixed point theorem.

Comment: Here's another way to look at it. Given $x$, let $y$ be the solution to $y=x+\sin y$. Replacing $y$ on the right hand side by $x+\sin y$ we get $$y=x+\sin (x+\sin y).$$ Continuing in this way we get $$y=x+\sin (x+\sin (x+\sin (x +\cdots )))).$$

Comment: @user55622 That isn't a proof of convergence, though.

Comment: No, of course not. But it's a trick they do with continued fractions.

Comment: @Jack M But is it periodic, what are  the time period, series general term and Fourier coefficients ?

Comment: Can it be plotted for successive nestings to show graphic convergence?