# Existence of unique fixed point in compact Metric space

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, fixed-point-theorems

Let $(X,d)$ be compact. Show: for a map $f$ that when $\forall x, y \in X$ with $x\neq y$

$d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ is fulfilled.

Then $f$ has a unique fixed point.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118536/prove-the-map-has-a-fixed-point?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Assume there are two fixed points, let $x$ and $y$.

As $f(x)=x$ and $f(y)=y$, then $$d(f(x),f(y))=d(x,y)<d(x,y),$$ a contradiction.

Comment: I don't see how compactness matters.

Comment: The statement $f$ has a unique fixed point means $f$ has a fixed point and it does not have more than one fixed point. Where did you prove the existence of a fixed point?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: the title led me to think that only uniqueness was to be established.

Comment: Even the title talks about both existence and uniqueness.

Comment: Extremely sorry. I didn't know the the title was changed.